# List all financial Assets data conditionally

Tags: curated-data, finance

I would like to get all the Financial Data that Mathematica respecting those constraints :

The assets for which there are at least 20 years of daily price quotations.
Or that have s price for each day the market has been open for at least 20 years.

or

The assets that have prices time resolution of 15 min available for at least 1 year.
That is I wil have 4 Price in each hour that the market has been open for at least 1 year.

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what the first constraint is asking for, could you clarify?

Comment: Do *any* of them have 15-minute data? PS congratulations on a very auspicious reputation level (888).

Comment: AUSPICIOUS, not suspicious. 888 is a lucky number in some cultures.

Comment: @verbeia ahaha, thank you very much it all make sense now wow, I had never heard/seen that word. 888 i my reputations :-) I took a screen shot, for my colleague from China !

Comment: I think that MMA gets its data (for stocks) from Yahoo!Finance, and they don't provided historical tick data as far as I know. To get all stocks that have 20 years of daily quotes, I think you'd have to check the length of the returned values for all symbols.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, `FinancialData` does not provide a way to query the length of data available for a particular stock. The only way of knowing it is to query the data and select those that have data for 20 years. First, let's get a list of all NYSE stocks with:

```
stocks = FinancialData["NYSE:*", "Lookup"];
```

Now, I have multiple interpretations for your 20 year constraint, so I'll address them below.

#### 1. The stock existed 20 years ago

This does not take into account if the stock exists at present. So, first we get the exact date 20 years ago with

```
date20yAgo = DatePlus[DatePlus[0], {-20, "Year"}];
```

and select those stocks that have data on that day. To account for that day being a Saturday/Sunday or any other public holiday, we retrieve data for the entire week:

```
existed20yAgo := ! FinancialData[#, {date20yAgo, DatePlus[date20yAgo, 7]}] === 
  Missing["NotAvailable"] &;

Select[stocks[[ ;; 20]], existed20yAgo] // Quiet
(* 
Out[1]= {"NYSE:AA", "NYSE:AAI", "NYSE:AAN", "NYSE:AAR", "NYSE:AB",
    "NYSE:ABA", "NYSE:ABK", "NYSE:ABK-PZ", "NYSE:ABM", "NYSE:ABN-PE"}
*)
```

I've just retrieved for the first 20 so that it runs in a reasonable time when you're checking. For the full list, remove the call to `Part`.

#### 2. The stock has existed for the past 20 years

You can simply modify the above example a little as:

```
existedForPast20y[stock_] := 
   FreeQ[! (FinancialData[stock, {#, DatePlus[#, 7]}] === 
       Missing["NotAvailable"]) & /@ {date20yAgo, DatePlus[-7]}, False]
```

You can do a quick check of the above with:

```
existedForPast20y /@ {"AAPL", "GOOG"}
(* Out[2]= {True, False} *)
```

You can use `Select[...]` as before and use this function to test.

#### 3: The stock has 20 years of historical data (any date range)

This will unfortunately require pulling all the data for each stock, and will definitely be slower.

```
has20yData := DateDifference[Sequence @@ (First /@ 
        Through[{First, Last}[FinancialData[#, All]]]), "Year"][[1]] >= 20 &
```

Again, replace the test function in `Select` with `has20yData`. I'll leave the rest of the constraints for you to work on.